# Modify a program I'm not the owner of

Tags: c, linux, assembly, cracking

For a website oriented on security, I have a challenge which consist in cracking an application.
It's the first challenge of that category, and I must admit I have no experience at all in this (and sadly no documentation is linked in that challenge).

So here I'm not asking for the answer, but more about a way to find it.

**The challenge :**

I connect using SSH to a machine, and get into this folder :

```
binary1@challenge02:~$ ls -la
total 24
dr-xr-x--x  2 binary1        binary1        4096 mai    4  2013 .
dr-xr-xr-x 14 root           root           4096 mai    4  2013 ..
-r-sr-x---  1 binary1cracked binary1        8059 mai    4  2013 binary1
-r--r-----  1 binary1        binary1         121 mai    4  2013 binary1.c
-r--r-----  1 binary1cracked binary1cracked   14 févr.  8  2012 .passwd
```

My user is binary1, and my goal is to read .passwd

Binary1 file is owned by binary1cracked user, as for .passwd, so I think it can read the .passwd file.
I take a look at the source of binary1 ;

```
binary1@challenge02:~$ cat binary1.c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
        system("ls /challenge/binary/binary1/.passwd");
        return 0;
}
```

There I'd like to replace the `ls` by `cat`.
But I obviously can't since I don't have write privilege on this file.

I'm stuck without an idea about what to do from here.
I thought about launching the program, have it hang at some point, and modify the memory to change the `ls` into a `cat` but I have no idea how to do this.

Am I on the good path? Any suggestions on how to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: For start try opening `binary1` it in a hex editor.

Comment: I did open it with an hex editor, but couldn't write it back since I don't have write privileges.

Comment: Since binary1 is setuid and invokes `system`, maybe you could invoke binary1 with a modified PATH and therefore do anything you want. For example, make your own version of `ls` placed into your custom PATH that reads the file rather than listing it

Comment: `binary1.c` file have user `binary1 ` and your user is also `binary1` right? So can change the read/write permission of `binary1.c`.edit it and change from `ls` to `cat`.

Comment: Interesting! I've fought of renaming cat to ls but didn't found how.
Though I'll look into PATH. Thanks!

Comment: @JKB I'll need to compile binary.c to execute it. And at this point it will make a binary file which will be owned by me with no rights at all over .passwd.

Comment: PATH should be the way.. modify PATH to make your home directory the first  directory in the PATH variable and create a shell script named 'ls' in your home directory to cat the .passwd file.

Comment: Yes, that was the way! thanks guys!

Comment: @Brandin mind making an answer about that so I can close the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `binary1` is setuid binary1cracked and invokes `system`, you should be able to invoke `binary1` with a modified `PATH` and therefore do anything that user binary1cracked can do. For example, supply your own version of `ls` that reads the .passwd file and place this `ls` into your custom PATH.

With bash you can supply a custom PATH by invoking a command like this at the prompt

```
 $ PATH=/my/custom/path ./binary1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I did something similar : `cp /bin/cat /tmp/ls` and then `export PATH=/tmp`

Answer (score 4):

The setuid bit is set on binary1 file so if you are able to execute the binary1 file after suitable modificaton you should be able to read the file.

binary1 file's group has execute permission... and the group is binary1 , so you would be able to execute the file.... and since the setuid bit is set, the owner of the process would be binarycracked which is also the owner of .passwd file. So if you are able to get the code to read .passwd into the binary1 file , you would be able to read .passwd.

Probable solution based on Brandin's hint..

```
PATH=~:$PATH; export PATH;
```

Place `ls` in your home directory with the content:

```
$ cat .passwd
```

And then execute

```
 $ ./binary1
```

Comment: exactly what I thought, but I have no idea how to edit this file.
Should I do that in memory during execution?

Comment: What was the content of the binary1 file?

Comment: binary1 is a binary made from binary1.c which I have cat in my question

Comment: Are you sure about it.. because the way has be to by executing the binary1 file ..and probably there would be a clue about how to open the .passwd file... is the binary1.c just a dummy there to trick you?

Comment: No, I don't think so.
Opening the binary file with an hex editor I get the same thing (plus some code linked to the c libraries stdio...)

Comment: PATH=~:$PATH; export PATH - make your home directory first directory in PATH variable , create a shell script named 'ls' in your home directory to cat the .passwd file .. and then execute binary1

Answer (score 3):

The important thing to know is that 'system' uses the shell to execute its argument, in particular, it calls

```
 /bin/sh -c "ls /challenge/binary/binary1/.passwd"
```

So, By knowing how /bin/sh finds the program 'ls' to execute, you can figure out how to replace it with something you want. This does not require editing any of the files given.