# using a modified ls to execute another program

Tags: c, linux, shell, terminal, ls

I got a modified `ls`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    gid_t egid = getegid();
    setregid(egid, egid);
    printf("This is a special NSA-modified 'ls' program. Due to security reasons it can only run 'ls' without user parameters.\n");
    system("ls -l");
    return 0;
}
```

I need to run the modified `ls` to run a program called `get-code`, but I don't know how to trick the `system` function in this code to not only execute `ls -l` but also the `get-code`. This is a course from school and I am allowed to ask on the internet from my teacher, the course is how to secure the programs better to not let any security gaps in the code.

Can someone help me? THIS IS NOT A DUPLICATE I just want to know how to trick the `system` so I can execute it with this `ls` code

Comment: Why do you repeat your question again?

Comment: i don't understand it i know that other question is not the same as mine.. pls just help me i am only 17 ok? i tried this for a long time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a local `ls`, such as

```
#!/bin/bash

/bin/ls -l
/courses/InetSec1/challenge6/get-code
```

then put this script (you should name it as `ls` and run `chmod a+x ls` to add execute permission to it) in some directory, such as `~/bin/`, and add this directory to your path by `export PATH=$HOME/bin:$PATH`.

After this, if you run that program again, it will run your local `ls`, because `system()` will run your command under a subshell, and that shell will search command needed to run in `$PATH`.

Exactly the answer given in [Modify a program I'm not the owner of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22113642/modify-a-program-im-not-the-owner-of)

Comment: thats is the point.. i cant make anything because i have none privileges.... thats the whole point of the course

Comment: @nick_rangercat What do you mean you cannot make anything? Which part you cannot do?

Comment: i can't make anything my privileges are just like a normal user.. i cant just make a program in the /bin directory so i can execute that program.. thats the part that i am geting very confused at

Comment: @nick_rangercat I did not say you need to add a program in `/bin`, I said `~/bin`, that is a total different directory. `~/bin` is the directory named `bin` under your home directory.

Comment: oh i see now i am going to try that right now

Comment: how to make a program in the bin? i made the mkdir bin in my home directory

Comment: @nick_rangercat Create a text file named `ls` in your `~/bin`, and include in it those four lines in my answer. If you know how to use a text editor, you should know how to do those.

Comment: yeah with cat > ls.txt *enter* "; /courses/InetSec1/challenge6/get-code" *enter* cntrl-d right?

Comment: http://puu.sh/7rb6B.png

Comment: @nick_rangercat I am asking you again, do you know how to use a text editor?

Comment: @nick_rangercat That is totally wrong.

Comment: no i dont in that case... like i said i dont know anything of linux, we just got the exercises and we needed to find out by our selfs

Comment: @nick_rangercat Then you should learn how to use Linux first, specific how to edit a text file in it. There are plenty of tutorials in the Internet, try to google some and learn.

Comment: @nick_rangercat It does not matter which text editor, any text editor works on Linux is enough for your current task.

Comment: thank you very much for your help! http://puu.sh/7rbTt.png it worked i will check you

Comment: @nick_rangercat I am glad your problem get solved.